# Absolute path work on a react project installation, but fails on another. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a project with create-react-app and do many staff on my office. On my imports im using no relative path on folders:

```
project-folder
 src
  components
  reducer
```

On my reducer folder i made a import like this:

```
import componentX from "components/mycommponent/componentX"
```

and on my office, works without problem.

On my home, i just download the project do 'npm install' a try to run the project

and the same file don't find the componentX and i don´t know why. I have several imports on that project and, if possible, don't want to change all my imports.

Can you guy know why this happen?

Comment: if possible share some code and tell me error of missing component is coming from your own component or from some 3rd party npm installed package ?

Comment: My own component. My original project don't have a .env file, but i folllow SakoBu's  advice and works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the root of the project create a `.env` file... To that file add `NODE_PATH=src/`

Now you do not need to use relative imports... (Note: since I don't know the exact directory structure of your project use some common sense and adapt the solution to your specific situation)

My guess would be that said `.env` file is probably in the `.gitignore` and you didn't get it when cloning the repo...

Answer (score 0):

In case error or missing component is of some node package the you most probably for got to add `--save` with package install and you package json is not updated.
then you can check by `ls node_modules` and check for missing dep in package json.

In other case  like error is from your code you have to share error and some code.

In case of any query ping me or update you question.
I will update my ans.